# Selenium: Not able to select the radio button

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, radio-button

I am trying to select a radio button using selenium, when I run script selenium doesn't select the radio button and moves to the next step without selecting the radio button without giving me any error.

Below is the HTML for the same:

```
<div class="col-12 scrolling pend active" id="mergeTransTable"> 
    <div class="title-table transactions">
        <div class="expenseDetailId" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <input id="hdnMergeOtherDataCount" name="hdnMergeOtherDataCount" type="hidden" value="0">
        </div>                                                                       
        <div class="comment" style="cursor: pointer;" width="20%">Comment
        <div class="vendor" style="cursor: pointer;">Vendor </div>                
        </div>
            <div class="receipt" style="cursor: pointer;">
                Receipt
        </div>            
    </div>            
    <div class="data-table transactions">
        <div class="expenseDetailId" data-title="ExpenseDetailId" style="margin-top:2%;">
            <input type="radio" name="ExpenseDetailId" id="ExpenseDetailId" class="chk" value="163867">
        </div>
        <div class="vendor" data-title="Vendor">AMAZON</div>                
        <div class="comment" data-title="Comment" width="20%">
            UBER
        </div>              
             <div class="receipt&quot;" data-title="Receipt">                    
                <a id="Receipt" href="abc.com" onclick="return ViewReceipt('/ExpenseDetailId=163867')">Receipt</a>                     
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is the xpaths I am writing for selecting the radio button

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mergeTransTable']/div[2]/div[1]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='mergeTransTable']//div[@class='expenseDetailId' or starts-with(@data-title,'ExpenseDetailId')]")).click();
```

Using the CSS doesn't help either.

Tried Java Script and Action class also but nothing seems to be working. Selenium just don't select the radio button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the input not the div tag.

```
//*[@id='mergeTransTable']/div[2]/div[1]/input
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it seems that you are "clicking" the `div` and not the radio button. Therefore nothing happens and there are no error messages. Why don't you directly click the element with id `ExpenseDetailId`?

`driver().findElement(By.id("ExpenseDetailId")).click();`

Comment: This doesn't work? `driver().findElement(By.id("ExpenseDetailId")).click();`